# Delete User doesn't work in JHipster Prod Mode

Tags: jhipster

I tried to use command: ./mvnw -Pprod,no-liquibase in JHipster3.0, When I login as 'Admin', and try to deleted an user from User Management, I got an error : error.internalServerError

But it's working fine in dev mode.

Comment: Where is the server log?

Comment: I found out all of Operation with Save, Create, Delete Entities doesn't work, produce the error : 500 (Internal Server Error), It means Post, Delete, Put Rest method doesn't work. Only Get method is working. And the server doesn't produce any log.

Comment: Set DEBUG for `org.springframework.web` and `org.springframework.security` loggers in `logback-spring.xml`, you should see what's wrong. Pay attention to the web mappings at the init phase..

Comment: I did set DEBUG  for org.springframework.web and org.springframework.security loggers in logback-spring.xml, The server still doesn't produce any log. I tried the command: .\mvnw -Pprod,swagger,no-liquibase. enable swagger, but it still doesn't work. but it's everything working fine in dev mode. By the way, my backend database is POSTGRESQL.

Answer (score 0):

I found out the reason why causes the problem, That's because in production profile using the following elasticsearch setting:

```
 data:
        elasticsearch:
            cluster-name:
            cluster-nodes: localhost:9300
```

but in dev profile using the other elasticsearch setting:

```
  data:
        elasticsearch:
            cluster-name:
            cluster-nodes:
            properties:
                path:
                  logs: target/elasticsearch/log
                  data: target/elasticsearch/data
```

By replacing dev setting to prod setting, it's working.